# 2D point extraction model, similar to classification without an activation layer at the end

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification

I'm trying to figure out how I could convert a classification model into a 2d point extraction model. i.e. Train on detecting 4 coordinates in an image (not classifying it).

It would make sense to remove softmax at the end, but I'm unsure of how I would train the model to match up against N number of coordinates. I'm not even sure how I would structure the labeled data.

Custom [Mobilenet](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/mobilenet.py) Example :

```
...
previous layer definitions
...

# final layer
def pool_and_classify(self):
            model = self.model
            model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7,7),strides=(1,1)))
            model.add(Flatten())
            model.add(Dense(self.classes))
            # model.add(Activation('relu')) #was 'softmax'

def create(self, size):
        self.model = Sequential()
        self.model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2), padding='same', input_shape=size))
        self.mobile_block(32,64)          
        self.mobile_block(128,128)
        self.mobile_block(256,256)
        self.separate()
        self.final_conv_block()
        self.pool_and_classify()
```

If I wanted 4 coordinates, the last dense layer could potentially be 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform regression in the final layer. For extracting `4` points you need to predict `8` values (x and y coordinate for each point). For `N` points in general you will need to predict `2N` values. So your last layer should be

```
model.add(Dense(2 * N))
```

You don't need to add any extra activation for regression. Also you will need to use mean squared loss instead of cross entropy loss used in classification.